# Update sails model without trigger lifecycle?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I know that `model.save({ silent: true }, callback);` is not supported. But anyone know how to update Sails model without trigger lifecycle event??

I have ask on github issue, but still no respond so far. Link is [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2702)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using .native()/.query() to execute your query, thus avoiding the call back.

Use `.native()` if your using MongoDB and use `.query()` if your running MySQL/Postgres

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/waterline/models/native.html

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/waterline/models/query.html